# How to handle "invalid character" errors with PHP xml_parse?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, invalid-characters

When parsing a file received from a trusted third party, I've an error `Invalid character (error code: 9)` caused by the invalid HTML entity `&#2;` *(see weird things below)*.

**How could I handle that kind of problem?** (so that the file is still parsed)
For example by simply deleting the invalid character.

As I need to handle large files (50MB), I'm using `fread()`. So it's not safe to check/clean the part read (`$data`) before passing it to the XML parser.

```php
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, FALSE);
xml_set_element_handler($parser, "startElement", "endElement"); 
xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, "characterData"); 

$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
  if (!xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
    $errorCode = xml_get_error_code($parser);
    printf(
      "XML Parser: %s (error code: %d). File: %s, line %d, column %d.",
      xml_error_string($errorCode),
      $errorCode,
      $file,
      xml_get_current_line_number($parser),
      xml_get_current_column_number($parser),
    );
  }
}
```

##### 3 weird things:

1. I've the same problem in 4 files (out of 24).
   All these problematic files have 2 times that invalid character, on 2 different lines.
   The error message is always the same, indicating the line number of the first occurence (the content is actually the same on both line, so the column is also the same, which is normal but probably wrong).
2. The same error message is displayed too many times.
   File 1: 126.38KB, 4 times. File 2: 11.70MB, 4 times. File 3: 36.64MB, 70 times. File 4: 4.55MB, 96 times.
   Note: `xml_parser_free($parser); $parser = NULL;` is called after each file. Anyway, PHP > 8.0.0, so not needed anymore.
3. The error message indicates the wrong(?) column number.
   The relevant portion of the line is `excellent technical know&#2;how in design`.
   The invalid character is at column 325 but the error message says 312 (which is the "e" in "technical").

Comment: Is `&#2;` a valid character in XML? Every parser I've tried says no. I would go back to your third party and ask them about it, they might have corruption on their side.

Comment: Tell whoever generated the invalid XML to stop doing that.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it's not a valid character and it's the third party's fault. My question here is how can I handle that kind of problem on my side, the way I want. That said, I'm looking for something not too complicated. And I'm fine with "there's no easy way".

Comment: I absolutely understand what you are saying. I once had a client send me what I thought was a corrupt file, and after way too much debugging on my side, I finally figured out it was EBCDIC. Which code page? I spent even more time debugging, figured it out, and then wrote a converter. Problem solved. Fast forward a couple of months and they told me someone else had a problem with that file and asked why it worked for me. I gave them my story and they said "Sorry, that was a bug on our side, we'll export as ASCII". Lots of time wasted on my side for a bug on their side.

Comment: Whether or not you care about that anecdote is up to you. To your problem, you need to start with the knowledge that you **do not** have an XML file, you have a binary file, and maybe a text file. To get an XML file, you'll need to perform, at a minimum, a string replace on `&#2;` to something else. What should you convert it to? No idea, you'll need to debug that. Once you do that, and fix any other edge cases, you might then have an XML file that you can run through a parser.

Comment: OK, thanks @ChrisHaas, that was the first thing I did. But it led to a 24-hour delay that I want to avoid in the future. I was asking here a specific question on purpose.
Regarding your "solution", it's not the right way to do it. I don't want to solve the `&#2;` issue, I want to solve the "invalid character" error raised by the XML parser. But OK, validating first the characters in the file could be an option… but as I'll have to read it also by chunks, it's actually the same problem 